# why am I gettig null for some parameters in jersy rest post method?

Tags: javascript, java, json, angular, jersey

I am trying to set up a rest endpoint with jersey. I am using an angular2 client.

the angular code looks like this:

```
  post() {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    this.http.post('http://localhost:8050/rest/addentity', JSON.stringify(this.getValues()), new RequestOptions({ headers: headers })).
    subscribe(data => {
                alert('ok');
          }, error => {
              console.log(JSON.stringify(error.json()));
          });

  }
```

The post is sent correctly and I can see in the payload that all the values are there.

However, for two values I always get null in the server. Here's the method:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("addentity")
public void saveEntity(User user) {
    System.out.println("ADD CALLED");
    System.out.println(user.getId()); // null
    addUser(user);
}
```

I have no idea why. The media type is correct, I get a 204 response...

Does anybody have any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**

JSON

```
{"id":"1234",
"name":"john",
"age":15,
"height":"6.2"}
```

User

```
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5320367665876425279L;

    private Integer userId;
    private String name;
    private double height;
    private int age;

    public User() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public User(final Integer userId, final String name,
            final double height, final int age) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.name = name;
        this.height = height;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Integer getuserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setuserId(final Integer userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getname() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setname(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public double getheight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setheight(final double height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    public int getage() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setage(final int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }


}
```

All values except height are `null` or `0`, so only the double value is read correctly.

Comment: What does the JSON look like and what does the User class look like?

Comment: @peeskillet I edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

Well your actual code shows many problems, from what we can state:

- In your `User` class you have an attribute `userId` while in your JSON you don't have it, it's `id` instead.
- And the getters and setters in the `User` class are incorrect they should have the attribute first letter in Uppercase, ie : `getage()` should be `getAge()` and `setage` should be `setAge()`.

You have to fix these problems otherwise your POJO won't be correctly mapped with your JSON.

You can refer to **[Getters and Setters in Java convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18046071/getters-and-setters-in-java-convention)** for further reading about it.