# Need some advice on dealing with many fields in Java

Tags: java

This might be a stupid question but I'm working on a 2-D Java game and one of my classes has a LOT of fields.

Rather than creating getters and setters for all these fields and cluttering up the class, I'm thinking it would be better to just create a primary get and set function that takes these arguments: 
- A string value with the name of the field I want to access
- the value itself to set the field to (setter function only).

Is there any better way for doing this that doesn't involve setting all the fields to public or package private or am I on the right track?

Essentially I'd create an array to hold all these fields but then I'd lose the convenience of NetBeans auto-complete when looking at functions for these fields.

Comment: You could look at using Lombok library

Comment: Lombok is one option, or roll some of those variables into a collection.  Or, perhaps your class is too cluttered and should be broken into multiple classes.

Comment: Maybe check out [AutoValue](https://github.com/google/auto/tree/master/value).

Comment: Have you considered `Properties`? If necessary, you can group properties by type but you don't have to if you don't mind the brittleness of having to know the type of a property based upon its name.

Comment: Netbeans' "Encapsulate fields" refactoring can save you the typing of all those getters and setters if that's what you're _actually_ trying to avoid.  But  you should really be considering the possibility of breaking up your class into several smaller ones, each with fewer fields.

Comment: @jeff6times7
Thanks, the Property class actually looks pretty good for my purposes

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is, implement your getters and setters. IDEs have wizards to help you on that (good), or you may use annotations: [Java Getters and Setters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907312/java-getters-and-setters) (good) or preprocessors (write your own program that parses your source code and writes the getters and setters for you)(maybe not so good).

Long answer is you can do exactly what you want, and if you dont want to type each member you can do this with the Reflection API: https://netjs.blogspot.com/2017/08/invoking-getters-and-setters-using-reflection-java.html

Reflection is not that important for a simple project, but may help you when writing an engine that will have advanced access to its entities (eg ingame debugging tools).